# load giant matrix of octave in python by scipy.io

Tags: python, scipy, octave

I want to load in python some matrix which has been produced in octave and saved as `.mat` file.
I save them as:  `save -v7 'y.mat' Y` or `save ('y.mat', 'Y', '-v7')`

one of matrices is 50 by 50 and the other one is 10,000,000 by 50.

I load them in python as:

```
import scipy.io as sio
Y = sio.loadmat('y.mat')
```

The smaller matrice has been loaded properly and output is a dictionary of an array and information about header, version and etc.

The problem is that bigger matric doesn't load and the result is `OSError: could not read bytes` 
complete error is as follows:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b5ea6427914d> in <module>()
----> 1 Y = sio.loadmat('y.mat')

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py in loadmat(file_name, mdict, appendmat, **kwargs)
    134     variable_names = kwargs.pop('variable_names', None)
    135     MR = mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)
--> 136     matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
    137     if mdict is not None:
    138         mdict.update(matfile_dict)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py in get_variables(self, variable_names)
    290                 continue
    291             try:
--> 292                 res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
    293             except MatReadError as err:
    294                 warnings.warn(

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py in read_var_array(self, header, process)
    250            `process`.
    251         '''
--> 252         return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
    253 
    254     def get_variables(self, variable_names=None):

scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:7578)()

scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:6575)()

scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_real_complex (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:8049)()

scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_numeric (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:4575)()

scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_element (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:4143)()

scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.streams.ZlibInputStream.read_string (scipy/io/matlab/streams.c:3261)()

scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx in scipy.io.matlab.streams.ZlibInputStream.read_into (scipy/io/matlab/streams.c:3185)()

OSError: could not read bytes
```

Is there any other way octave/matlab or format to save which would be more easier or at least possible to load in python?

I have also tested to save without version(which the result was a giant file) or in other versions.

Comment: Why use mat-files in the first place? You can simply output a 50-column wide binary file and then load that.

Comment: octave also natively supports the hdf5 format (see [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#Simple-File-I_002fO)). you could try saving to that, and reading it back into python with the [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/) package or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are running out of memory space.

10e6*50 gives 500e6 values. If saved as double result in about 4 GByte of memory.

I did run into memory issues using Python under Spyder IDE on my windows PC.
The application was retrieving curves from an oszilloscope using pyvisa. The oszilloscope curves where 6 channels with 30 million points per channel. When keeping all the curves in memory at the same time I experienced sporadic errors. When using only 1 million points per channel the programm ran without any issues. I guessed, that python / numpy can only process data up to 2 GBytes in memory.

As I needed the 30 million points, the solution for me was to process the curves one by one. So I only had one curve in memory at the same time.